# The use of verb stem in the sentence

Tags: grammar

Why in this sentence the stem of the verb is used instead of the verb 炒める itself?

> まず、玉葱を炒め、次に肉を入れて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often in literary or written formats, you will see the 'verb stem' used in this way as a less 'colloquial' alternative to the て-form. So your example can also be rendered as follows:

> まず、玉葱を炒め**て**、次に肉を入れて下さい。

See also this thesis entitled ["On Japanese Coordinate Structures:
An Investigation of Structural Differences Between the -te and the i-form"](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=osu1392805640&disposition=inline), if you are interested to read a rather more detailed treatment on the subject!

Hope that helps!